# iText : unable to print ÷ symbol

Tags: itext

I am using  Times New Roman Font to get mathemetical symbols. I got most of it but unable to get `÷` symbol either  by using unicode notation `\u00F7` or by directly printing it. Its printing some other  symbol.
Here is my code :

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("/home/adeel/experiment.pdf"));
                TableHeader event = new TableHeader("Header");
                writer.setPageEvent(event);
                document.open();

                Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/TimesRoman.ttf");
                String FONT = null;
                try {
                    FONT =  resource.getFile().getPath();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                BaseFont bfTimes = null;

                try {
                    bfTimes = BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Font fontnormal = new Font(bfTimes, 12);

                String text = "Divide by example : 45 \u00F7; 3";
                // String text = "Divide by example : 45 ÷ 3";
                Paragraph para = new Paragraph(text, fontnormal);

                document.add(para);
                document.close();
                writer.close();
```

Comment: *Its printing something else.* - you don't embed your font. probably the replacement font your viewer uses instead does have a different symbol (something else) where you font resource has the division sign.

Comment: Does the font TimesRoman.ttf has the char?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A font may not have all the char or may have different mapping for the same char as compare to other font. For eg.  Divide symbol has different mapping in TimesRoman as compare to Verdana font. Fortunately Verdana worked for me for most mathematical symbols.